# How to get list of registered consumers in MassTransit?

Tags: masstransit

is there a way how to get list of all registered consumers? Right now I need to write a test, that make sure, that all required queues has registered consumers. That is unfortunately impossible or at least I don't know a way.

My test should cover that scenario, when you forget to register one and it's quite hard to find out, unless you're using request/response scenario, when it throw a timeout exception.

And Moq is not helping that much, because mostly it is generic methods (like AddConsumer) with constraints which is quite a problem when verifying certain method was called with specific parameters. I can replace it with calling non-generic, but that I would like to use as last resort.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After the container is configured, you could use the `IServiceCollection` directly to check if registrations exist.

```
Assert.That(services.Any(x => x.ServiceType == typeof(SomeConsumer));
```

Do that for each consumer.

Comment: I didn't think about recreating the whole services container, but I looked into Moq and couldn't find other way around how to be able to to use their Verify method in case of generic method with constraints. This is probably the best idea. Thank you.